# Error when I redirect page 404 to my login page it does not have css and does not accept html in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I use these to redirect page 404 to my page login:

```
router.get("/login", (req, res) =>{ res.render("auth/master"); });

router.get("*", (req, res) => { res.redirect("/login"); });

router.get("/", (req, res) => { res.render("main/layout/home"); })
```

it was run but my home page and login page do not accept html and console notice that:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3001/login".

login:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web page HTML code probably contains a URL reference to a style sheet. That style sheet URL is probably incorrect, or maybe you have not yet created the style sheet.

The error message you received in your browser's console

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3001/login".

happens when a style sheet URL is incorrect. The server sends an error page (404 page maybe) to your browser, with something explaining the error. The browser says to itself, "wait, this is supposed to be a style sheet but it's not" and shows this console message.

`View Source ...` is often a good way to troubleshoot this kind of thing.

Comment: what the view source can you explain more clearly for me ? please...
i have added style sheet it still run if remove :

router.get("*", (req, res) => { res.redirect("/login"); });